# How can I specify the machine in docker swarm mode?

Tags: docker

In docker swarm mode, I can use 'replicas' to control the service quantity, but how can I control them in which machines

Answer (score 1):

1.add label to node

```
docker node update --label-add  role=manage centos7-t2
```

2.use `placement` in yml

```
deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.labels.role == manage
```

3.Start

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml swarm
```

4.View the distribution

```
docker service ps swarm_nginx
ID            NAME           IMAGE         NODE        DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE          ERROR  PORTS
tzk410pdxpww  swarm_nginx.1  nginx:latest  centos7-t2  Running        Running 5 seconds ago         
p35evqnkr3su  swarm_nginx.2  nginx:latest  centos7-t2  Running        Running 4 seconds ago
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some control by adding lables to the machines and constraints to the service. But otherwise, the scheduling is left to the swarm.

Comment: What lables,can you give me some example? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean to use "docker node update --label-add " ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I just quickly checked the documentation but was not able to find a good reference.

Comment: @StrifeCloud how is it solved can you provide a feedback?